# Production And Development Project Environments

Tags: python, django

We have a legacy tool developed in Python using Django and is running live on Apache  mod_python module.

Now we have an issue in the tool and to debug that we have no dev setup. I have got the access to code as in TAR ball but I am unable to bring up the DB connections / tool. I want to use the same settings as it is running in production, but bringing the app up using the same config give me below error:

```
python manage.py runserver xx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxx
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named MySQLdb
```

Running a MySQL DB instance on localhost does solves the issue but it does not helps me as I do not have access to datasets.

Please let me know how a setup in dev is possible by accessing LIVE DB hosted in another box (able to ping from dev box) with only read dataset permissions. However for starting however it could be fine with other DB permissions also if not possible.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Install the MySQLdb module and the MySQL client libraries.

Comment: Please let me know the setup details regards to dev and production boxes? What configuration changes / modifications I would need to make?

Comment: You would need to install the MySQLdb module and the MySQL client libraries.

Comment: I assume you are stating installation in Dev boxes - but how to I setup dev app to talk to production DB

Comment: You wouldn't. That would be insane. Set it up to talk to the dev database.

Comment: Setting up app to talk to Dev box will not help us at all - cause we cannot debug prod issues without DB datas. So is there a workaround for same?

Comment: you *could* arrange for a read only mysql user account against a production database, or take a mysqldump of the production database, load it on a dev mysql server and use that.

Comment: @Prakash: Dump your production database and import it into your development database. You never, ever, *ever* do development against a production database. That's insanity.

Answer (score 1):

Do a data dump from the production system using manage.py dumpdata and then populate your dev db.

Once you have that, install MySQLdb on your dev box, adjust settings.py to point to your dev db server, then run the app.

Worth mentioning that you should run all this in a virtual environment with the exact version of django (and other dependencies).

Comment: Thanks, will try this but since the app is legacy I am also not sure which tables, constraints are enforced on its DB schema? Is there a way I can also know the DB schema complete details so that I can create same on dev side or is it that the prod dump will provide the same?

Comment: Once you syncdb, your databases will be replicated (assuming production DB was managed through django).